# Escaping String in JQuery on .ajax submit to submit to mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, escaping, form-submit

I have a simple HTML form that I have to submit using JQuery.ajax.

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="mySite/data.php" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="30"/>
    <label for="text">Text:</label> <br/>
    <textarea class="required textarea" cols="60" id="request" name="request"  </textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
</form>
```

And the JQuery.ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var frm = $('#myForm');
  frm.submit(function () {
    if(frm.valid() == true){
         $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url: frm.attr('action'),
              data: frm.serialize(),
              success: function (data) {
                    alert("Your Request Has Been Received. Thank You.");
                }
            });  
    } else {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid Request");
    }
    return false;
    });   
</script>
```

The form data is saved to a mySQL database and then displayed on another page using more JQuery.ajax. Between these pages and the database I have php pages to read and write the data, here:

```
switch($_REQUEST['action'])
{
case "submit":
    addRequest($_GET['name'], $_GET['content']);
    header('Location: myPage.html'); 
    break;

}

if(isset($_POST['request'])){
$content = stripslashes($_POST["request"]);

echo "<h3>Here is the Request You Just Entered: </h3><br/>";
echo "<table width=40%><tr><td style='font-weight:bold;'>Name: </td><td>" . $name . "</td></tr>" .   "<tr><td style='font-weight:bold;'>Your Request: </td><td>" . $content . "</td></tr></table>";
$name = addslashes($name);
$content = addslashes($content);

echo "<br/><a style='padding-right:3%;' href='?action=submit&name=" . $name . 
         "&content=" . $content . "'>Submit Request</a>";

echo "<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Back to the Site</a>";

die();
} else {
echo "No Data Submitted";
}
?>
```

The page displays all the content properly but when I've displayed the information being sent to my addRequest() function, the data is not escaped and it causes problems.

Everything works great unless the text input needs to be escaped. I've debugged the system and found that my strings need to be escaped BEFORE I submit the form data with JQuery.

How would I properly do that, or is my problem something different? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: _"my strings need to be escaped BEFORE I submit the form data with JQuery"_ - No, because someone could bypass that. Escape for mysql just before your mysql query, and escape for html just before displaying the html.

Comment: Yes that's true but the problem is that if my strings aren't escaped before the function is called then it will cause problems with the function itself. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to escape anything in jQuery, as `.serialize()` takes care of encoding everything properly.

However, you need to URL-encode when creating a URL in an anchor tag:

```
echo "<br/><a style='padding-right:3%;' href='?action=submit&name=" . urlencode($name) . 
     "&content=" . urlencode($content) . "'>Submit Request</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to escape in Jquery :

```
function addslashes(string) {
return string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').
    replace(/\u0008/g, '\\b').
    replace(/\t/g, '\\t').
    replace(/\n/g, '\\n').
    replace(/\f/g, '\\f').
    replace(/\r/g, '\\r').
    replace(/'/g, '\\\'').
    replace(/"/g, '\\"');
}
```